# Why does not Python specifies errors more deeply?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm curious why does not Python specifies errors more deeply? I'm getting this error right now.

```
firms[i]['predmet_podnikania']=firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'][:-1]+[firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'][-1]+line]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Ok, I get that I'm trying to access some list on highest index than the maximum is. But why Python doesn't tell which list is it?

It can be: `firms[i]` or `firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'][-1]`

It would save a lot of time.

Comment: This is the price you pay for cramming many operations onto one line.  If you space the code out a bit the errors will be more meaningful.

Comment: BTW in both `firms[i]` and `firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'][-1]` you are using `firms[i]` to access an element so the value of `i` is the root cause of IndexError

Comment: I dont think that it is true. This means only that if firms[i] is not callable, firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'][-1] raises the same error. But if we have a list firms[i]['predmet_podnikania'], which has 0 length but exists, it can raise the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is raised in `list` class. It is not possible to get variable name (`firms`) inside `list` methods so the exception contains a generic message .